# Are decorators that are classes called different than decorators that are functions?

Tags: python-3.x, decorator

Consider the following to decorators

```
class MethodDecoratorC(object):
    def __init__(self,func):
        self.func = func
    def __call__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        print(len(args))
        print(len(kwargs))
        self.func(*args,**kwargs)

def method_decorator_f(func):
    def wrapped_func(*args,**kwargs):
        print(len(args))
        print(len(kwargs))
        func(*args,**kwargs)
    return wrapped_func
```

They look to do exactly the same, and for functions that's true:

```
@MethodDecoratorC
def test_method_c(a):
    print(a)

@method_decorator_f
def test_method_f(a):
    print(a)

test_method_f("Hello World! f")
test_method_c("Hello World! c")
```

prints:

```
1
0
Hello World! f
1
0
Hello World! c
```

For methods however, something very strange happens:

```
class TestClass(object):
    @MethodDecoratorC
    def test_method_c(self,a):
        print(a)

    @method_decorator_f
    def test_method_f(self,a):
        print(a)

t = TestClass()
t.test_method_f("Hello World! f")
t.test_method_c("Hello World! c")
```

prints:

```
2
0
Hello World! f
1
0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test5.py", line 40, in <module>
    t.test_method_c("Hello World! c")
  File "test5.py", line 8, in __call__
    self.func(*args,**kwargs)
TypeError: test_method_c() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
```

Not much expected! Somehow the TestClass object is not transferred as an argument to the `__call__` method of my decorator object.

Why this difference? And is there a way that I can still obtain the object in my class style decorator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`self` being bound to the first argument for instance methods works only because methods are wrapped in [descriptors](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#implementing-descriptors). When `obj.meth` is requested, not found in the object and then found in the class, the descriptor's `__get__` method is called with some information including the object, and returns a wrapper around the actual method object that, when called, calls the underlying method with the object as additonal/first argument (`self`).

These descriptors are only added for actual functions, not for other callable objects. To make a class with a `__call__` method work like a method, you'll have to implement a `__get__` method (see link above).